# Macro to find and replace text in text file (loop for different files)

Tags: vba, excel

new to VBA but trying to make a macro for the following:

- I want the macro to open a text file (location provided in cell A2
  with file name in cell B2), to find the text (provided in cell C2),
  replace the text with new text that is provided in cell D2, and then save and close the text file.
- Then, it should open a text file (location provided in cell A3 with
  file name in cell B3), to find the text (provided in cell C3), replace the text with new text that is provided in cell D3, and then save and close the text file.
- Repeating until all the files provided in the spreadsheet have been
  updated.

Thanks for you help!

Example of spreadsheet:
[spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qImrf.jpg)

Note that I'd like to be able to find and replace text that don't necessarily have to have the same number of characters as the original text.

Attempt so far is below. When running debug, the `strText` is correct when hovered over, then when it passses the `Get #i, , strText` step, it changes to be the header of the text file that is I am trying to update.

```
Sub Replace_Text()
Dim src As String, fl As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim strText As String
Dim lngMyRow As Long
Dim lngLastRow As Long

i = FreeFile

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lngLastRow = Range("A:B").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1

For lngLastRow = 2 To lngLastRow
x = 2
'Source directory
src = Range("A" & x)
'File name
strFile = Range("B" & x)

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    Open src & "\" & strFile For Binary Access Read Write As #i
      strText = Space(LOF(i))
      Get #i, , strText
            For Each cell In Range("C1:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
                .Pattern = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "?", "\?"), "*", "\*"), "+", "\+"), ".", "\.")
                strText = .Replace(strText, cell.Offset(, 1).Value)
            Next cell
            Put #i, , strText
        Close #i

    End With
    i = i + 1
    Next lngLastRow
    MsgBox "done"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry, should I have added my edits to the answer? I'm new to VBA (never used it before today) and new to the forum so just finding my feet. I tried the `strText = Space(LOF(i))` but it just gives the header of the text file.

Comment: FWIW - `For lngLastRow = 2 To lngLastRow` should be `For x = 2 To lngLastRow` and similarly `Next lngLastRow` should be `Next x`, and the `x = 2` statement should be removed.  The hover text on `strText` will show only the data contained within the variable up to the first CR/LF, so will only show the headings.  And `i = i + 1` is probably redundant - you should be able to re-use the same file number for all your files.  After those changes your code should (as far as I can tell) be working.

Comment: I'm sorry but those changes do not work. When trying to run it comes up with a file path error. Happy to start from scratch again as like I said, new to VBA, have just taken lines from other macros I found.

Comment: you made no mention of saving the file

Comment: I updated the question to include saving the file. Thanks.

Comment: @jsotola The file is opened for read/write access, and the `Put` is doing the write.  The `Close #i` closes the file with the new contents included.

Comment: Please give a sample of the information in column A and column B.  E.g. what are the values in A2 and B2.

Comment: Ohh - Nothing to do with the file path error, but `Put #i, , strText` is probably meant to be `Put #i, 0, strText` or `Put #i, 1, strText` (it's been a long time since I used it, so can't remember whether it is 0-based or 1-based, start by assuming it is 0-based)  Nope - it is 1-based, so use `Put #1, 1, strText`.  (BTW, if the new string is shorter than the original string, the file will still contain parts of the original data.)

Comment: Which line of your code is giving the file path error?  Assuming it is the `Open`, what are the values of `src` and `strFile` when it crashes.  Does the file specified by those variables exist?  Do you have read/write access to that file?  Is the file in use by some other user, or some other application?